# How to search a List of objects using specific property

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I'm trying to search a `List<Word>` collection, where `Word` is my class with property `Name` and add each element that is contained into a given string array into a `List<string>` collection. ie.

```
class Word
{
    public string Name;//Name property
}

var words = new List<Word>();
var recognized = new List<Word>();
```

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
theSentence.Split(new[] {' '}).ToList().ForEach(s => words.Where(w => w.Name == s).ToList().ForEach(recognized.Add));
```

Is this code healthy? Is there a way I can do `if(words.Contain(Name property))` in .NET?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That doesn't look like a good idea to me, no. Just use LINQ more simply (and more efficiently):

```
var recognized = theSentence.Split(' ')
                            .Join(words, x => x, word => word.Name,
                                  (x, word) => word)
                            .ToList();
```

Or as a query expression:

```
var recognized = (from x in theSentence.Split(' ')
                  join word in words on x equals word.Name
                  select word)
                 .ToList();
```

(As an aside, I note that the `Name` "property" is actually just a public field. Hopefully it's a real property in your actual code :)

For this part:

> Is there a way I can do `if(words.Contain(Name property))` in .NET?

I would create a new set:

```
HashSet<string> wordNames = new HashSet<string>(words.Select(x => x.Name));
```

Then you can just use:

```
if (wordNames.Contains(...))
```

... and it will be an O(1) operation (assuming no hash collisions etc) instead of having to check every word each time.

EDIT: Addressing this comment:

> Is there possibly a way I can get the elements of the collection not found by Join and put it in another list say... Unrecognized List

Yes - if you're happy that you only have one `Word` with any given `Name`, or you've overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in `Word`, you can use:

```
var unrecognized = words.Except(recognized).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! I was just trying to provide a hint of what it looks like. Also, only [Exsaliver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655416/how-to-search-a-list-of-objects-using-specific-property/9655486#9655486) responded to my second question. Is this the only way to do it?

Comment: Is there possibly a way I can get the elements of the collection not found by Join and put it in another list say... `Unrecognized List<Word>`?

Comment: @opatachibueze: Will edit the answer - too much code to show in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code doesn't do anything, If you want select words with available name in theSentence you can do as below:

```
var recognized = theSentence.Split(new[] {' '})
                           .SelectMany(x=>words.Where(y=>y.Name == x))
                           .ToList();
```

Also you can add distinct to prevent from redundant data.

Comment: That will end up with a `List<string>` instead of a `List<Word>`. It's also rather less efficient than a join.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I changed my answer to return list of words, but I don't know why you say join is more efficient?

Comment: For `x` words in the list and a sentence of `y` words, yours is O(x*y). Mine is O(x+y) by building a HashSet in the background. It takes a bit more memory, but is significantly more efficient when `x` and `y` are large.

Comment: So join uses hashset? am I right? I didn't know this before. I know you are reference, but do you have any reference to read more about linq background structure (like this one)?

Comment: Yes, it uses a set in the background, to make the equijoin efficient. You can look at my blog posts about my own alternative implementation of LINQ to Objects for more information: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have a list of known words:

```
var words = new List<Word>();
```

And you want to see which words are present in a sentence:

```
string sentence = "The cat is on the table";
```

All you have to do is use LINQ like this:

```
var found = sentence.Split(' ').Where(word => words.Any(known => known.Name == word));
```

In your code you are misusing LINQ because you are adding elements into a list by yourself bypassing all the LINQ magic.

**EDIT:** Sorry, I didn't see you were trying to get a list of words! In that case use `Join` method as suggested by Jon Skeet. Alternatively just append a `Select` operator at the end and re-create the word class:

```
found.Select(a => new Word() { Name = a });
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean:

```
        if (words.Count(n => n.Name == "name") > 0)
        {

        }
```

Comment: It's better to use `Any` than to check with `Count` - that way it can return `true` as soon as it's found any matches. But see my edit - using a `HashSet<string>` would be more efficient.